# Type [Node] does not conform 'Equatable' in Swift 4.0?

Tags: arrays, swift, eureka-forms

I use Eureka in my Project,and I want use type [Node] for Cell's Value type:

```
final class TreeTVCell: Cell<[Node]>,CellType{//#1:compiling Error in Swift 4.0

}
```

As you know , Cell's Value type must conform protocol Equatable，and class Node wrote by Objc,it's very simple:

```
#import "Node.h"

@implementation Node

- (instancetype)initWithParentId : (int)parentId nodeId : (int)nodeId name : (NSString *)name depth : (int)depth expand : (BOOL)expand{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        self.parentId = parentId;
        self.nodeId = nodeId;
        self.name = name;
        self.depth = depth;
        self.expand = expand;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

My project compiled OK in Swift 4.1 (Xcode 9.3.1),But if I open project with Xcode 9.2 (Swift 4.0),it will be comiled failed, it's complain that :

> Type '[Node]' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

my Q is why it's compiled ok in Swift 4.1 and failed in Swift 4.0? 
and How to fix it in Swift 4.0? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Swift 4.1, Arrays of Equatable are not themselves Equatable. This isn't something you can fix in 4.0 directly; it lacks conditional conformances. You would have to wrap the Array in some other type (we usually call it "boxing" the type) and make that Equatable. Upgrade to Swift 4.1.

See [Conditional Conformance in the Standard Library](https://swift.org/blog/conditional-conformance/) for more details.

Comment: I think you are right! So I had to wrap [Node] to other class to fix it ! THANKS!!